# Como identificar o click em um drawableLeft

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte `EditText`:

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mPasswordTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_24dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/login_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Este é um campo do tipo de senha!

Gostaria de identificar o clique no drawable ( `android:drawableLeft` ) para alterar o `inputType`!

Para isso fiz o seguinte:

```
    mPasswordTxt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final EditText editText = EditText.class.cast(v);

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                final float click_X = event.getRawX();
                final float icon_width = editText.getCompoundDrawables()[0].getBounds().width();
                final int left = editText.getPaddingLeft()+editText.getLeft();

                Log.d("CLICK" , ("click_X:"+click_X));
                Log.d("CLICK" , ("icon_width: "+icon_width));
                Log.d("CLICK" , ("left:"+left));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

O Log de um click em cima do ícone:

> D/CLICK: click_X:253.65059
>
> D/CLICK: icon_width: 96.0
>
> D/CLICK: left:8

Acho que o valor de `event.getRawX()` está muito alto (acredito que esteja contando o início da tela)

Como faço para descobrir que o usuário clicou em cima do `drawableLeft`?

Answer (score 2):

Fiz alguns testes aqui e funcionou bacana para o `DawableLeft`. O calculo proposto é verificar se a coordenada do evento clicado é menor ou igual  o tamanho do espaço esquerdo mais o tamanho do ícone definido. Basicamente essa é a condição: `if(click_X <= (left + icon_width)`. Veja o `onTouchListener` abaixo:

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final EditText editText = EditText.class.cast(v);

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                //Retorna a coordenada X original do evento 
                float click_X = event.getRawX(); 
                // tamanho do dawable left / icone
                float icon_width = editText.getCompoundDrawables()[0].getBounds().width();  
                int left = editText.getPaddingLeft()+editText.getLeft();

                if(click_X <= (left + icon_width)) {
                    // Aqui será a área clicada correspondente ao dawable left / icone
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicou no icone",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Cara, consegui utilizando o **getX()** ao invés de **getRawX()**!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski você chegou a testar esta forma como fiz?! Vou verificar testar aqui a precisão dos dois métodos.

Comment: Sim, sim! Em um exemplo com o **rawX** ele me retorna **103.94634** Com o **x**  me retornou **23.946342**  Sendo o **icon_width: 36.0** + **3** de **left**

Comment: Vi vários exemplos que usam o **getRawX**, até achei meio estranho... Fiz os testes em 3 telas diferentes e funfo de boa!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski legal. Você pode colocar uma resposta, ou até mesmo editar a minha acrescentando sua experiência se preferir. Boa sorte ai.

Comment: Vo fazer, vou apenas testar mais um pouco! Valeu pela ajuda Bro!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui detectar o clique no `DawableLeft` utilizando o `getX()`, ao invés do `getRawX()`

Segue a implementação:

```
   passwordText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final EditText editText = EditText.class.cast(v);

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                final float _x = event.getX();
                final float icon_width = editText.getCompoundDrawables()[0].getBounds().width();
                final int left = editText.getPaddingLeft()+editText.getLeft();
                if(_x <= (left + icon_width) ){
                    Drawable _Drawable = null;
                    if(editText.getInputType() == 129){
                        editText.setInputType(1);
                        _Drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_lock_open_24dp);
                    }else{
                        editText.setInputType(129);
                        _Drawable =  context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_lock_24dp);
                    }
                    int _width = (int)icon_width;
                    _Drawable.setBounds(0,0,_width, _width);
                    editText.setCompoundDrawables(_Drawable, null, null, null);
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```